# ViewPagerAndroid not showing inside ScrollView (using Reacnative)

Tags: react-native, android-viewpager, scrollview, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to use `ViewPagerAndroid` inside `ScrollView`, but nothing is rendered like this.

[image]

After i add `contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1 }}` into `ScrollView`, `ViewPagerAndroid` will render correctly but the whole page will not be able to scroll like this
[image]

(The whole page can not scroll just `FlatList` part can be scrolled)

This is a page container

```
    <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <CustomHeader/>
        {Platform.OS === 'android'
          ? (
            <CategoryViewPager>
              <View
                key="0"
                style={styles.viewContent}
              >
                <DishesListContainer />
              </View>
              <View
                key="1"
                style={styles.viewContent}
              >
                <Text>Second page 2</Text>
              </View>
            </CategoryViewPager>
          )
          : (
            <Text>IOS Support later</Text>
          )
        }
      </View>
    </ScrollView>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
  viewContent: {
    paddingLeft: dimens.level_12,
    paddingRight: dimens.level_12,
  },
})
```

This is `ViewPager`

```
// CategoryViewPager/index.js

  <View style={styles.container}>
    <CustomTabsButton/>
    <ViewPagerAndroid
      style={styles.viewPager}
    >
      {this.props.children}
    </ViewPagerAndroid>
  </View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  viewPager: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: setColors.mainBg,
  },
})
```

This is `FlatList` part

```
// DishesListContainer/index.js

const DishesListContainer = props => (
  <View>
    {props.isShowTitleBar && (
      <CategoryTitleBar />
    )}
    {props.dishes && (
      <FlatList
        style={styles.listContainer}
        data={props.dishes}
        keyExtractor={item => `${item.pk}-${item.sk}`}
        numColumns={Dimensions.get('window').width > 600 ? 3 : 2}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <DishesList
            photoUrl={item.photoUrls[0]}
            name={item.name}
            priceRange={item.priceRange}
          />
        )}
      />
    )}
  </View>
)
```

So how can i make `ViewPager` showing correctly and also make `ScrollView` works fine (Scroll the whole screen)

Thanks!

Comment: were you able to get a solution to this?

Comment: @DhavalJardosh have not touch this for so long, could not remember anything, so sorry.

Comment: No problem, I was having this issue last night, but got a quick fix. Not suitable for all, but at least we can work with that.